# print_r doesn't go to next line

Tags: php, bash

I'm trying to run a bash script in php; also, i want to see the log of the bash script. So, my php file looks like something like this:

```
<?php
    $message=shell_exec("/var/www/html/judge/uploads/MyScript.sh 2>&1");
    print_r($message);
?>
```

"Myscript.sh" is this :

```
    #!/bin/bash
    printf "MyScript \nran \nsuccesfully"
```

And the output is:

```
MyScript ran successfully
```

But i want the output to be something like this:

```
MyScript
ran
successfully
```

What should i do?

Comment: if you view your HTML source, you will see the line breaks are indeed there. If you want to see them on different lines "on screen", you need to use `<br>` or `nl2br`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @AdrienLeber I just noticed your comment about `nl2br`, which I did add to my comment before yours, *just saying* ;-) edit: ah, you deleted your comment. I take it you saw mine also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks. Solved.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an answer below as a community wiki should you wish to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki; I don't want rep from this.

As per my comment:

If you view your HTML source, you will see the line breaks are indeed there. If you want to see them on different lines "on screen", you need to use either `<br>` or `nl2br()`.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php